# Unable to get post value from select after POST in Django

Tags: python, django, forms, drop-down-menu, html-select

Hello everyone I am new to `Django` and I have tried a bunch of different approaches I have found online yet I still cannot get the value from my select dropdown after `POST`. Even after I hardcoded the value as 1 just to test it I still wasn't able to get the value. The dropdown is getting populated correctly which means `{{ d.name }}` works. Originally I had the value set to `{{ d.name }}` as well. I did not use `forms.ChoiceField` as I wasn't aware of this yet when I made my form. Here is my code:

forms.py

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyList
        fields = ['field1', 'field2', 'field3' ]
```

Template:

```
<div  class="form-group pull-right">
  <label class="control-label" for="apply"> Apply: </label>
      <select class="span4" name="apply" id="apply">
        {% for d in devs %}
            <option name="somename" value=1>{{ d.name }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</div>
```

views.py

```
def View(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MyForm(request.POST or None)

        if form.is_valid():
            print(request.POST["apply"])
```

models.py

```
class MyList(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False, unique=True)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    field3 = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
```

Thank you in advance for all your help.

Comment: try to `print request`

Comment: print `request.POST` on top of the view

Comment: Why are you trying to get the `apply` field when you specifically set up the form to only have `field1` `field2` `field3`?

Comment: Where exactly? I get an error MultiValueDictKeyError if I print before the if statement

Comment: `fields = ['field1', 'field2', 'field3' ]` means the form will have _only_ those fields.  It has no `apply` field.

Comment: I have other fields in the form besides the dropdown named field1 field2 field3

Comment: Your template may be displaying those fields because you hardcoded them in, but the `MyForm` object is ignoring them because they aren't part of its definition.

Comment: i tried to add apply to the forms now I get this error: Unknown field(s) (apply) specified for MyList. {{ d.name }} works which shows a list of devs passed from the views

Comment: It's too confusing to keep track of piece-by-piece changes.  Edit your question to include all of your updates.  Also include the definition for `MyList` in `models.py`.

Comment: Ok I reverted everything back to the original code in my post. I edited my post and added the models.py. I am still unable to get the value from the select option. Thanks for taking the time to answer my questions.

Comment: When the user submits the form, Django will only accept fields that are part of the form definition.  `apply` is not a valid form field because it's not in the `MyList` model.

Comment: OK I finally got this code to work. Thanks John for pointing me in the right direction